# How to find default property values of a control at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a control ...any **System.Windows.Forms.Control**. say for eg. label.

I wish to find the default value for its property called "Enabled" (can be any property for that matter). How do I do it?

1) See, in this case, we have a label. The label's default value for the property "Enabled" is true.

2) Now at runtime, suppose I wish to find out what is the default value for the property "Enabled"...how do I find out?

3)To start with I have an object of my control. From that object, I can only get the current value for the property "Enabled" but not the DEFAULT value.

One possible approach to this question could be:

1)Identify the control's type at runtime.
2)Initialize it using its default constructor.
3)Find the value of the property we are interested in (It will obviously be the default value) and there..we have the default value.

But, in this case..I don't know my control before hand. All i know is , that it can be any control from **System.Windows.Forms.Control** . So how do I even initialize it and get its object? Is it possible?

Do you have any alternative solution/ better approach?

Comment: There is not really any concept of a control having a "default" value. The Visual Studio designer may give controls default values when they are added to the form, but these are just written to the .designer file e.g.

myControl.Enabled = true;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to use reflection! Here's a method which should get the default value of any property for any type which has a default constructor (public, no parameters):

```
public static object GetDefaultPropertyValue(Type type, string propertyName)
{
        if (type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }) == null)
            throw new Exception(type + " doesn't have a default constructor, so there is no default instance to get a default property value from.");
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        return type.GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, new object[] { });
}
```

Note that if you are doing this with a large number of controls of which there can be multiples of a single type, you may want to cache the results for each type, as reflection is somewhat slow.

Comment: You may also want to consider pulling the "DefaultValue" attribute as well and reading that as well:type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute), false)

Answer (score 3):

You can instanciate an (at design time) unknown object using generics.

```
public class DefaultValueChecker<T> where T : System.Windows.Forms.Control, new()
{
    public bool DetermineDefaultValue() {
        var control = new T();
        return control.Enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: That requires *knowing the control beforehand*, which is explicitly ruled out in the question. `T` may be unknown at design time within your `DefaultValueChecker<T>` class, but any calling code needs to know `T` at design time.

Comment: The question says "I have [...] any System.Windows.Forms.Control". And that's exactly what my example requires. Please re-read the question, then my answer.

Comment: It also says *I don't know my control before hand. All i know is , that it can be any control from System.Windows.Forms.Control.* This sounds like the control type is not known, so it cannot be used as a type argument.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be generally found out. Default values may be either of the following:

- hard-coded
- dependent on (exchangeable) resources
- dependent on system settings

With your suggested approach, you can at most find hard-coded values. However, you won't have any way of telling whether they are really hard-coded.

As for the second part of the question, this can be solved by using reflection: Have a look at the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) class (runtime type information) and the [`Activator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class (runtime type instantiation).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using reflection and checking for DefaultValue attribute:

```
Type labelType = typeof(Label);
DefaultValueAttribute attr = (DefaultValueAttribute)labelType
    .GetProperty("AutoEllipsis")
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Defaul tValueAttribute),true)
    .FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(attr.Value);
```

However, not all properties are annotated with this attribute, so not all default values can be obtained this way.

Comment: Actually this attribute is only used to compare the current value with a "default" in order to know if the values has changed and needs to be highlighted bold in a property grid.